# ebtable rules to block traffic at bridge interface

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, traffic

I have a setup, one bridge is connected together with 3 ethernet ports eth1,eth2, eth3. How can I block the traffic from a client which is connected to eth1, based on client's MAC at bridge, br0 using ebtables?

Comment: You only want to block traffic from a MAC to a specific device? If he connects to eth2 or eth3 you don't want to block him? May I ask what is the purpose of that? Why not block this MAC for the bridge? Are you concerned the same MAC appears on two different networks?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands:

```
ebtables -A PREROUTING -d <MAC> -i eth1 -j DROP
iptables -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source <MAC> -j DROP
```